# Calling a method in OnGet within Razor Pages

Tags: c#, methods, constructor, razor-pages

I'm trying to create a method as a property for a Page Model and call that method within my `OnGet` method in the same Page Model so I can assign the call to another property. It doesn't seem to be displaying it on the view page. Not sure what I'm missing.

Attempting this with the generated template app:

```cs
namespace RazorPage.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public string Username (string name)
        {
            return name;
        }

        public string Person {get; set;}

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
                    string Person = Username("John");
        }
    }
}
```

Calling it in my view page as:

`@Model.Person` and nothing renders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared local variable `Person`:

```cs
 public void OnGet()
 {
   string Person = Username("John");
 }
```

But you need to assign property `Person`:

```cs
 public void OnGet()
 {
   Person = Username("John");
 }
```